# Css background fix

Tags: html, css

I can not understand how to remove the top and bottom of the strip , and that would be in other places it was normal .

```
    <div class="ma_linenums">
                <div class="ma_linenum">
                    <div class="num">1</div>
                    <div class="text">Provide ship to zip code</div>
                </div>
                <div class="ma_linenum">
                    <div class="num">2</div>
                    <div class="text">Select Box-n-Go storage containers to be shipped</div>
                </div>
                <div class="ma_linenum">
                    <div class="num">3</div>
                    <div class="text">Confirm who will be receiving the shipment</div>
                </div>
                <div class="ma_linenum">
                    <div class="num">4</div>
                    <div class="text">Confirm all the information provided</div>
                </div>      
                <div class="ma_linenum">
                    <div class="num">5</div>
                    <div class="text">Box-n-Go representative will calculate the shipping costs and provide you with a quote</div>
                </div>  
                <div class="ma_linenum">
                    <div class="num">6</div>
                    <div class="text">Once we recive your approval, we will shio the items to you</div>
                </div>  

                <div class="clearfix"></div>        
            </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h49hsx89/1/

Need result: http://cs624027.vk.me/v624027836/285ae/thJS61-9ct8.jpg

Comment: to clear, so you want to remove the extra vertical line both at the top and bottom, right?

Comment: need clear top and bottom line, yes

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Please be more specific and provide a problem plus desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/x3596yn4/3/

The following will fix it:

```
.ma_linenums {
  background: url("http://cs624027.vk.me/v624027836/2858b/qWSCfsvYM3I.jpg") repeat-y;
  background-size: 1px 90%;
  background-position: 27px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Originally your picture was repeating the entire height of its container. I restrict this via `background-repeat: no-repeat` and manually set the height to `250px`

If you want to make the height of the line resize to the content then change `background-size: 1px 250px;` to `background-size: 1px 90%;`

Comment: If you want to make it resize to its container than replace the `250px` with `90%`. This value seems to work. Editing my reply to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in the code, and use pseudo class instead to obtain the desire result. Check out this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h49hsx89/4/

Here is the css I added to make it possible:

```
.ma_linenum:before {
    content : '';
    background: url("http://cs624027.vk.me/v624027836/2858b/qWSCfsvYM3I.jpg") repeat-y;
    height:22px;
    width:1px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:13px;
    top:-10px;
}

.ma_linenum:first-child:before {content:'';background:none}
```